# Bash on Windows 10 does nothing and goes back to command prompt

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just today `bash` on my Windows 10 machine has completely stopped working.  Running `bash` from the command prompt results in about a one second pause, and then returns immediately back to the command prompt.

[image]

I have already tried removing and reinstalling "*Windows Subsystem for Linux*" from *Turn Windows features on or off* (several times) with associated reboots (see below):

[image]

**What else could I possibly do to get `bash` working again?**

--- Edit with additional information ---

Output of `wsl.exe -l -v` showing distributions and versions installed on my local machine:

[image]

For further context, the `Ubuntu` and `Debian` images were installed *after* I started experiencing the problem with the `bash` command prior to today.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 version 2004 (build 19041.867)

Comment: According to Microsoft's documentation on WSL (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference) `bash` remains full supported as invoked directly from the command line.  There is also a list of deprecated commands at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some deleted comments, but for clarity, Microsoft calls `bash.exe` a "historic command" in that page you linked to. I don't consider it "deprecated" (since, as you point out, they explicitly list deprecated commands).  But "historic" is, IMHO, just one step before "deprecated."  Also, the [WSL/Windows Interop documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#earlier-versions-of-windows-10), says "`bash.exe` has been *replaced with* `wsl.exe`" (emphasis added).

Anyway, the *recommended* way of launching is (currently) certainly through the `wsl.exe` command, since it provides many more options and is more robust.  It's also possible for distributions such as Alpine to not even include a `bash` shell, so it's a bit of a misnomer anyway.

Not that `bash.exe` itself is likely your problem.  It's just that you'll probably need the features of `wsl.exe` to recover.

You note that you installed the Ubuntu and Debian *after* this problem started happening.  Does this mean that you were *only* running the Docker Desktop prior to this?  A typical installation for WSL is to:

- Install the WSL feature itself (along with the WSL2 kernel)
- Install a distribution
- Then install Docker Desktop

However, if you only had the two `docker-desktop*` instances, it would seem that you never installed any other distribution.  This isn't really recommended.  The `docker-desktop` instance *is* launchable, but I believe it is really designed for Docker Desktop's internal use (e.g. setting up the Docker sockets).  I could be wrong on this ...

As to why `bash.exe` is no longer launching your default `docker-desktop` container, I'm not sure, but it's likely something to do with your bash startup configuration.  When WSL exits without any error message, that's usually due to a problem *inside* the instance.  WSL does not appear to redirect stderr back to the host, or perhaps it just needs some redirection to do so that I haven't delved into yet.

To try to find out what's going wrong *inside*, try launching with any of the following:

```
wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc # Launches without any startup profile
wsl -u root # Launches as root instead of the default user
wsl -e sh # Launches the dash shell instead of bash
wsl -u root -e sh # Same as above, but as root
```

If one or more of those work, then you can begin troubleshooting your startup configuration from there.  If you are able to launch as root, then you can `su yourusername` to switch to your user.  Since you are launching from *inside* the WSL instance, you should be able to see any error messages that could be suppressed when running from the Windows command prompt.

Ultimately, though, I'd recommend you set a different distribution as default, via:

`wsl --set-default Ubuntu`

You can still get back to the *"docker-desktop"* distribution to copy out any needed files via `wsl -d docker-desktop` (append any of the previously discussed options if those help you launch it without error).

Comment: Deprecating bash and replacing with an another exe, which does very much the same thing is a typical Microsoft play book. All that effort for the sake of a name, when all they needed to do was link bash.exe to wsl.exe and all this needless confusion would be prevented. The only good that's come out of it is that Bash.exe and WSL.exe can have different colors.